# Is there a term for using cover to artificially block AI attacks?

Tags: terminology, first-person-shooter

One of the key techniques for playing the original Doom games was to stand with a wall, column, or other terrain feature between the monsters and you, such that your ray-traced bullets passed through, but enemies shooting fireballs or other projectiles with size were blocked. Arachnotrons were particularly susceptible to this exploit. I'm sure a thousand other games have this phenomena, though hopefully modern AI is smarter about *moving* when the target is blocked.

Is there a term for this technique?

To be clear, I'm not talking about simply using cover, or dodging out from cover to take a shot and then retreating, but rather situations were you can stand still and cherry-tap the target to oblivion with your pistol, perfectly safe.

Comment: Abusing the limits of the AI?

Answer (score 6):

#### You are *exploiting* the AI

The player is using meta-knowledge about the AI of a particular game to gain an (unfair?) advantage. This fits the definition of [*to exploit*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exploit):

> to use (someone or something) in a way that helps you unfairly

I hear this term being used often in relation to technical Minecraft, where many automated farms rely on some sort of exploit of game mechanics (such as villagers slightly outside of a village breeding to repopulate that village). And in relation to exploiting the AI of the Mossman in the Swamplands Fractal of Guild Wars 2 by standing on a tree, making the enemy unable to hit you.

Comment: That's too general, if that's the best term for it then the answer is no. I swear there is a word for this specifically but I can't think of it...

Answer (score -4):

Yes there is, It is called a Wallhack.

> A cheat that makes walls translucent. Some wallhacks also let players shoot weapons or physically pass through walls.

Although this term is usually used for an actual cheat, I believe it serves to explain exactly what is happening in your game. It could also be called an exploit, but you are in fact not exploiting the AI, but your surroundings.